# How can I prevent google hangouts from popping up "randomly" when I use Chrome and have lots of tabs open?

Tags: google-chrome

How can I prevent google hangouts from popping up "randomly" when I use Chrome and have lots of tabs open?

And why is it happening?

I'd also be interested in whether I can isolate what tab causes it, but i'd like to disable that from happening anyway.

Comment: Can you remove the Google Hangouts extension in Chrome?  That will stop the pop ups but only if you do not use Hangouts in your work.

Comment: @John I just went to tools..extensions.. typed 'hang' in the search and hangouts didn't come up. Though I have lots of chrome profiles so it's possible it is in one of them

Comment: Perhaps remove all extensions, remove Chrome, restart the computer and install the newest version.

Comment: @John I found two profiles with hangouts, i've disabled hangouts in each of those. I wouldn't want to click some button to remove all extensions from all profiles, and no such option exists anyway.  Anyhow, I found two profiles where I had it and have disabled it there. Will see in time if that makes a difference. Thanks

Comment: Removing the extensions in the other profiles will probably fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to stop most unwanted Chrome behavior is to remove the associated extension(s).

Can you remove the Google Hangouts extension in Chrome? That will stop the pop ups assuming you do not use Hangouts in your work.

**note added by barlop**  I have many chrome profiles, i've looked through them, and found two that had google hangouts, they may have been the culprits. I've disabled the extension in those profiles. I expect that removing the extension from any profiles that have it, (or rather, any profiles in use, that have it), is the answer. Time will tell if that works, but I think it will.